# Big Query using a CTE twice on the same query performance

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Lets assume I have something like the following simplified query for big query:

```
WITH test AS (
  SELECT 1 AS fieldA, 2 AS fieldB
)

SELECT fieldA, fieldB
FROM test
UNION ALL
SELECT fieldB, fieldA
FROM test;
```

Will Big Query run the `test` CTE twice or only once and then share the data between both parts of the union?

I searched before posting this and I know that a CTE query only lives for one SQL statement. But here - there is only one statement which uses same CTE twice and I could not find something similar.

Of course CTE query is more complex in real life scenario and might contain a ROW NUMBER window function and also JOINS.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Agree with @MikhailBerlyant. I suspect it will only run once. However, I recommend reading this documentation on BQ query plans and taking a look at your Execution Details. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-plan-explanation

Comment: BigQuery only materializes the results of recursive CTEs, but does not materialize the results of non-recursive CTEs inside the WITH clause. If a non-recursive CTE is referenced in multiple places in a query, then the CTE is executed once for each reference. The WITH clause with non-recursive CTEs is useful primarily for readability - see more in documentation - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with_clause

Comment: In essence, an CTE is just a way to save typing the same code twice. Or a way to extract a complex step. But really it is not different from a subquery. SQL is a declarative language, meaning you write *what* result you want, not *how* to get the result. As a result, the database engine is free to choose how to the result you described. It may decide not to run the CTE at all (the way you've written), but incorporate it completely differently in the execution plan. I don't know `bigquery` well, but I'm sure it has a way to show you how the query is executed (`EXPLAIN` is used in other systems)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with_clause) is clear for the tables in the `with` clause (CTE).

> BigQuery only materializes the results of recursive CTEs, but does not
> materialize the results of non-recursive CTEs inside the WITH clause.
> If a non-recursive CTE is referenced in multiple places in a query,
> then the CTE is executed once for each reference.

This can be tested by adding a column with `rand()`. For each usage it will have its own value.

```
WITH RECURSIVE test AS (
  SELECT "normal" AS fieldA, 2 AS fieldB, RAND() AS R),
  test_recursive AS 
  (SELECT "recursive" , 9, RAND() AS R
  UNION ALL SELECT * FROM test_recursive
  WHERE FALSE )
SELECT * FROM test
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM test
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM test
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM test
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM test_recursive
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM test_recursive
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM test_recursive
order by 1
```

All real recursive CTEs have the same value for the random one. Therefore, the CTE was only caluculated once.

[image]

This query also shows that with two extra lines every CTE can by materialized.