# Getting filepath in BigQuery using recursive CTE

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following two tables to give me the filepaths that each user has:

```
create temp table object as (
  select 1 id, 'MyFile1' name union all
  select 2 id, 'MyFile2' name union all
  select 3 id, 'MyFolder' name union all
  select 4 id, 'SomeFile' name union all
  select 5 id, 'Hello' name
);
create temp table path as (
  select 1 user_id, 1 object_id, NULL parent_folder union all
  select 1 user_id, 2 object_id, NULL parent_folder union all
  select 1 user_id, 3 object_id, NULL parent_folder union all
  select 1 user_id, 4 object_id, 3 parent_folder union all
  select 2 user_id, 5 object_id, NULL parent_folder union all
  select 2 user_id, 1 object_id, NULL parent_folder
);
```

For example, for user-1, his directory structure looks like this:

```
MyFile1
MyFile2
MyFolder/
    SomeFile
```

I am trying to build a recursive cte such that it displays the user and their paths. Here would be what the query should return:

```
user_id           path
1                 MyFile1
1                 MyFile2
1                 MyFolder
1                 MyFolder/SomeFile
2                 Hello
2                 MyFile1
```

I currently have the following working query but was wondering if it would possible to improve this in terms of either readability or performance:

```
create temp table object as (
  select 1 id, 'MyFile1' name union all
  select 2 id, 'MyFile2' name union all
  select 3 id, 'MyFolder' name union all
  select 4 id, 'SomeFile' name union all
  select 5 id, 'Hello' name
);

create temp table path as (
  select 1 user_id, 1 object_id, NULL parent_folder union all
  select 1 user_id, 2 object_id, NULL parent_folder union all
  select 1 user_id, 3 object_id, NULL parent_folder union all
  select 1 user_id, 4 object_id, 3 parent_folder union all
  select 2 user_id, 5 object_id, NULL parent_folder union all
  select 2 user_id, 1 object_id, NULL parent_folder
);

WITH RECURSIVE all_paths AS (
    SELECT user_id, id, name AS path FROM path JOIN object ON path.object_id=object.id WHERE parent_folder IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT all_paths.user_id, null, CONCAT(all_paths.path, '/', object.name) 
    FROM all_paths JOIN path ON all_paths.id = path.parent_folder join object ON path.object_id=object.id
) SELECT * FROM all_paths ORDER BY user_id, path
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach you have chosen works and is good. There is another join in the RECURSIVE join part. This does makes the query not easy to read. A good practice is to join the data before or after the RECURSIVE join, which is possible in your case. Building the joined table as a temporary table or making it permanent with `select * from ... where false` will reduce processing power and time. Here I used all CTE statements, you can easily switch to temporary table by commenting out the comments.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
#create temp table 
object as (
  select 1 id, 'MyFile1' name union all
  select 2 id, 'MyFile2' name union all
  select 3 id, 'MyFolder' name union all
  select 4 id, 'SomeFile' name union all
  select 5 id, 'Hello' name
),

#create temp table 
path as (
  select 1 user_id, 1 object_id, NULL parent_folder union all
  select 1 user_id, 2 object_id, NULL parent_folder union all
  select 1 user_id, 3 object_id, NULL parent_folder union all
  select 1 user_id, 4 object_id, 3 parent_folder union all
  select 2 user_id, 5 object_id, NULL parent_folder union all
  select 2 user_id, 1 object_id, NULL parent_folder
),

#WITH RECURSIVE
path_name as ( # This includes path information and the name
  SELECT user_id, id, name AS path, parent_folder
  FROM path JOIN object ON path.object_id=object.id
  union all Select * from path_name where false # make this table permanent
),

 all_paths AS ( #RECURSIVE add all data
    SELECT * except(parent_folder) from path_name 
    WHERE parent_folder IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT all_paths.user_id, null, CONCAT(all_paths.path, '/', path_name.path) 
    FROM all_paths JOIN path_name ON all_paths.id = path_name.parent_folder  
)
SELECT * FROM all_paths ORDER BY user_id, path
```

Comment: great answer, my one comment is you don't need the the `WHERE false` predicate for the `path_name` to work, you can just remove the entire `union all...` and it will still work as a non-recursive cte. For example: https://gyazo.com/ccc4bc2a4ac3eb7ee2c9af0c42e004f5.

Comment: @David542 you are right the `union all` part with `WHERE false`  is not needed. However,  it can help speed up the query. If you do not use this, the CTE is run twice in the background. Please see here why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73437406/big-query-using-a-cte-twice-on-the-same-query-performance/73437934#73437934